# Behaviour of const conversion operator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

In the below code there is a conversion operator for converting class A object into const class B object.

My question is when the const B object is been created, why its value change as
b.v=20 gives no error.

Probably, i am missing some thing.

Thanx in advance

```
class B
{
public:
    int v;
    B() : v(10) {}
};

class A
{
public:
    operator B() const {}
};


void g(B b)
{
    b.v=20;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    g(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for edit. I will take care of it next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` after member function signature has nothing to do with return type; it only means that the function (or value returned by it) will not change *state* of the original object, i.e. will not change members other than those marked as `mutable`.

Additionally, your function `g()` takes parameter by value, so it's copied anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You function accepts parameter *by-value*, so it's a copy of what is returned, and it's not `const` - so you can modify in the body.

```
void g(B b)
```

Comment: You mean to say that the value returned by operator B() const {} will be stored in a temporary and then object b would be constructed from it by copy-constructor.

Comment: @Luv, there is no intermediate temporary, the value returned by Luv (an instance of `B`) will be used to copy construct the argument to the function (`b`). You can test this for your self, insert some debug statements in the copy constructor for example... (I am ignoring optimisations that a compiler may do..)

Comment: But it needs to be stored somewhere to be passed into the copy constructor to construct argument to the function b.

Comment: @Nim, your answer is still missing the real meaning of `const` in `operator B()` signature...

Comment: @Griwes, IMO the real question (why you can modify `b`) has no relation to the `const` attribute of the conversion operator. Anyways, you've answered that bit, no need for a duplicate answer...

Comment: @Luv, there is a temporary, it's constructed within the conversion operator (you've not inserted the code above) - this is passed directly to the copy constructor for the function argument.

Comment: @Nim, I think the real confusion (as opposed to question that arose from it) was caused by misinterpreting of what that `const` means...